# PHP Fatal error: Cannot call overloaded function for non-object

Tags: php, apache

I've been seeing a lot of this errors on my apache error_log.

My setup:

- I have 15 different websites that use the same PHP helpers repository (located in /usr/share/myphphelpers/helpers.php
- On each website I call the helpers.php file via require_once('/usr/share/myphphelpers/helpers.php')
- This error occurs on a specific function - all websites call this function (the event is user-triggered)

Could this be because all websites use the same resource file/function? What can I do?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Turn ON debugging in php.ini to catch exactly what is going on. It would close you to solve the problem.

Comment: What's the property name on the .ini file?

Comment: It's not going to be due to multiple websites using the same file/function. Can you provide the relevant code?

Comment: This happens while validating an array that represents a contact. Eg.:
`Array
  'name' => 'tix',
  'email' => 'test@example.org'`

I then perform several validations, including checking the mx record for the domain name - I already use APC to cache this results

Comment: e.g. what? Please show at least the line of code where the error message points to.

Comment: Sorry I've hit Enter without finishing the example. Its updated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not yet sure of what portion of code was triggering this error, I know it was caused by **server overload**.

I had two m1.small Amazon instances running under a Load Balancer but they could not handle all the traffic. Adding another instance solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if they all work on the same file, then do this: add lines

```
<?php
    // ...
    if(!empty($_COOKIE[$dev = 'dev']) || !empty($_GET[$dev])){
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', true);
    }
    // ...
```

in file where the error is and see what happens, the parties will work, and you check one thing, only you will see all errors.

Of course you have to add a cookie `dev=1` or `dev=1` to url.

Comment: *Don't use such techniques, because the revenge*... what?

Comment: @MathieuImbert Sorry, my english isn't good, one config or helper for many sites isn't good reason.