# What does the error "PHP Fatal error: cannot call overloaded function for non-object" means?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have WordPress website running on a GoDaddy Linux host. The error `PHP Fatal error: Cannot call overloaded function for non-object in wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 529` is being happening at random, usually in response to a POST request, I think.

- WordPress version: 3.8
- PHP version: 5.4.23

Line 529 of file `wp-includes/class-wp.php` is the body of the following function in class WP:

```
function init() {
    wp_get_current_user();
}
```

The error seems to be somehow related to the presence of the [WooCommerce plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/woocommerce/). I haven't seen the error when the plugin is deactivated.

Unfortunately, removing WooCommerce is not an option so I need to discover how is the error being triggered and provide a solution. The problem is I don't know what to look for.

**I want to understand what causes an error like the one above in a general case.**

- Can anyone provide an example of PHP code that generates such an error? or
- an explanation of why it happens?

**I'm hoping to be able to use that information to find a similar problem in WooCommerce's source code.**

I took a quick look at PHP's interpreter source code ([here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/44dcdd146d36c91dddc9b89b4679074fdbf2e183/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#L2030) and [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/Zend/zend_execute_API.c#L996)) and found the line that generates the error message, but to be honest, that didn't help me.

A [question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505901/php-fatal-error-cannot-call-overloaded-function-for-non-object) about the same error in a different application has an answer indicating the problem was caused by server overload. I don't think that's the case here. We don't get too much traffic.

A [different question in WordPress SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44016/php-fatal-error-cannot-call-overloaded-function-for-non-object-in-wp-includes-c) offers two possible causes. Either the problem is associated with Alternate PHP Cache (APC) being enabled or the problem is caused by a plugin. Unfortunately nobody offers actual solutions or specific causes.

My case is similar to the one exposed in the question above: I have APC enabled (currently trying to get help from GoDaddy to disable it) and my tests suggest WooCommerce has some responsibility.

I appreciate all your help.

Comment: If it was a memory usage issue, apache is going to throw an every about memory being exhausted, rule it out. What it seems is as if the SQL connection has been lost, "gone" even. can you do `global $wpdb`; before that call, and then `print_r($wpdb);` and then `exit();` and see if you're getting a db oject?

Comment: Hi @Ohgodwhy, I'm getting a wpdb object. Please see the output of that `print_r` call in https://gist.github.com/wvega/9107173.

Comment: Can you use an AddHandler and go back to PHP 5.3.x and observe for awhile to see if the issue persists? I've done some digging around and  I've found that some bad modifiers in preg_replace can cause this particular issue as well because the proper object doesn't get constructed in php 5.4+

Comment: Are you on shared hosting?

Comment: @AndrewSchools, I believe so. I have a **Economy Linux Hosting with cPanel** in GoDaddy.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I was able to switch to PHP 5.3.27 from the cPanel. I think you were right because I haven't been able to reproduce the error again since I changed the PHP version. I tested both with APC enabled and disabled.

Thank you a lot. I think that's going to be the solution for us. If you post an answer I will accept it.

I still would like to make it work in PHP 5.4 in the future. Do you have additional information about those bad modifiers used in preg_replace?

Comment: I ask about the shared hosting because you said you didn't get that much traffic, however, in a shared environment, your neighbors could be.

Comment: You're right @AndrewSchools. Thank you. I thought about it after you made the question. So far it seems like switching to PHP 5.3.x removed the problem, but I'll keep an eye on server load if things go wrong again.

Answer (score 1):

Go to root directory and create a php.ini file and write the following
;extension=apc.so

and save.

Neighbourhood Wordpress theme had this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this for individual sites by adding **php_flag apc.cache_by_default Off** to .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

We found that this is related to the APC module for Apache. To resolve it, simply edit your php.ini to uncomment the apc module so it reads from

```
extension=apc.so
```

to

```
;extension=apc.so
```

This will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the white screen of death for some time.
Prior to that a related issue -PHP Fatal error: Cannot call overloaded function for non-object in wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 529. This issue was solved by upgrading my godaddy account.

As mentioned above, the white screen issue could either be a plugin or the APC.
The fastest way to determine if it is a plugin is NOT to deactivate them all and then reactivate **one-by-one** - but rather deactivate and reactivate **all at once** - the plugin causing the problem with get an error reactivating.

That said, I wanted to keep the plugin so I contacted Godaddy, who readily disabled the APC.

I have reactivated the plugin and all seems fine.
The only potential issue with disabling the APC is slower load times, but I haven't experienced that yet.