# Fatal error: Cannot call overloaded function for non-object

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I am getting this error below:

Fatal error: Cannot call overloaded function for non-object in catalog/layer/filter.phtml on line 57

This happens on seldom occasion and I can seem to fix it temporarily and after a while, it comes right back.

```
switch ($attributeName)
{
   case 'Overthreshold':
        _displayDropdown($this,$displayitemcount);
        break;

   default:
        _displayOrderedlist($this,$displayitemcount);
        break;
}
```

Above is the overall line in question, but it shouldn't have anything to do with that code per say as I use the exact same coding on 15 other sites currently. This and one other site has this issue going on. No one else does.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897786/what-does-the-error-php-fatal-error-cannot-call-overloaded-function-for-non-ob. Simply, it's problem with APC cache module

Comment: I saw this. The option to simply turn apc cache off in the htacess for me creates an Internal Server Error.

Comment: _displayOrderedlist($this,$displayitemcount); -- This is line 57 by the way.